# Java exception specification for the main method

Tags: java, exception

Do we not need exception specification for the main method in a Java program. For example, the following code works exactly the same without specifying "throws Xcept" for the main method.

```
class Xcept extends Exception {
     public Xcept(){
     }
     public Xcept(String msg){
         super(msg);
     }
}

public class MyException {
    public void f() throws Xcept {
        System.out.println("Exception from f()");
        throw new Xcept("Simple Exception");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Xcept {
        MyException sed = new MyException();
        try {
            sed.f();
        } catch(Xcept e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Reached here");
        }
    }
}
```

I read that java enforces this, but I don't get a compile time error if I exclude this specification for the main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `Xcept` will never be thrown out of your `main` method, as you actually `catch` it there... The `sed.f()` call may result in an `Xcept` being thrown, but it's caught and handled.

Comment: Thanks.I guess I had not understood "throws" correctly. This helps.